# Score over time

Tags: game-maker, timer

I have the following code for adding 1 to `global.score` in the step event:

```
global.score +=1;
```

The problem is this adds the score at an alarmingly fast rate, I want to slow this down so I can give a semi realistic score that is going to represent distance. I am making an endless runner.
I have tried to slow the room down but it just messes everything up.
I tried to create an alarm event but to no avail.

using

```
alarm[0] = 10;
```

But I'm not 100% sure how to use the alarm properly.
How would I go about slowing down how much `global.score` takes?

Comment: what about using a timer?

Comment: how do i use a timer? and how would i use it in this context? im struggling to figure a way out.

Comment: I believe a timer is about the same thing as what you called an "alarm event". You can look for "how to timer gamemaker".

Comment: How about you use [real numbers](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/maths/real%20valued%20functions/index.html) instead?

Comment: So would this allow me to add a metric into the game? and calculate distance based on actual distance?

Comment: I don't know game maker at all, but why don't you add the actual distance travelled?

Comment: distance is calculated using pixels. Im not sure how i would translate this into a score that looks feasible to a user. I think ill give it a try though, its probably the best solution thanks.

Comment: Why not just add 0.3 or something like that instead of 1? Is that the minimum you can add? Also, you could just display score / 10 instead of displaying the score as it is and use it like that in situations that require it.

Comment: i prefer to use 1 as showing score is easier on a whole number. and im not sure on the dividing it by 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a timer like this:

In your Create event *(or where you want to start your counting)*:

```
alarm[0] = 1;
```

Then in your Alarm 0 event:

```
global.score +=1;
alarm[0] = 10; // how many gamemaker steps until this alarm get's called again
```

A step in gamemaker is the same as fps, default is 30 so 1÷30 = 0.033334 seconds.

Comment: ill try this now and post the results. This may actually be what i was after.

Comment: I changed alarm[0] = 0; to = 1 otherwise it wont instantiate the alarm, but this does work how i wanted and fits in nicely with my code, thank you.

Comment: ups, yeah that's true. fixed my answer

Comment: It's better to use the `room_speed` variable, like `alarm[0] = room_speed / 3`;